# extract sequences from multifasta file by ID in file using awk

Tags: search, awk, bioinformatics, multiline, fasta

I would like to extract sequences from the multifasta file that match the IDs given by separate list of IDs.

FASTA file seq.fasta:

```
>7P58X:01332:11636
TTCAGCAAGCCGAGTCCTGCGTCGTTACTTCGCTT
CAAGTCCCTGTTCGGGCGCC
>7P58X:01334:11605
TTCAGCAAGCCGAGTCCTGCGTCGAGAGTTCAAGTC
CCTGTTCGGGCGCCACTGCTAG
>7P58X:01334:11613
ACGAGTGCGTCAGACCCTTTTAGTCAGTGTGGAAAC
>7P58X:01334:11635
TTCAGCAAGCCGAGTCCTGCGTCGAGAGATCGCTTT
CAAGTCCCTGTTCGGGCGCCACTGCGGGTCTGTGTC
GAGCG
>7P58X:01336:11621
ACGCTCGACACAGACCTTTAGTCAGTGTGGAAATCT
CTAGCAGTAGAGGAGATCTCCTCGACGCAGGACT
```

IDs file id.txt:

```
7P58X:01332:11636
7P58X:01334:11613
```

I want to get the fasta file with only those sequences matching the IDs in the id.txt file:

```
>7P58X:01332:11636
TTCAGCAAGCCGAGTCCTGCGTCGTTACTTCGCTTT
CAAGTCCCTGTTCGGGCGCC
>7P58X:01334:11613
ACGAGTGCGTCAGACCCTTTTAGTCAGTGTGGAAAC
```

I really like the awk approach I found in answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26144692/printing-a-sequence-from-a-fasta-file) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38491388/use-awk-to-search-through-fasta-file-given-a-second-file-containing-sequence-na), but the code given there is still not working perfectly for the example I gave. Here is why:

(1)

```
awk -v seq="7P58X:01332:11636" -v RS='>' '$1 == seq {print RS $0}' seq.fasta
```

this code works well for the multiline sequences but IDs have to be inserted separately to the code.

(2)

```
awk 'NR==FNR{n[">"$0];next} f{print f ORS $0;f=""} $0 in n{f=$0}' id.txt seq.fasta
```

this code can take the IDs from the id.txt file but returns only the first line of the multiline sequences.

I guess that the good thing would be to modify the RS variable in the code (2) but all of my attempts failed so far. Can, please, anybody help me with that?

Comment: `awk 'NR==FNR{ids[$0];next} /^>/{f=($1 in ids)} f' file.ids file.data` https://stackoverflow.com/a/39898676/6260170

Comment: I would use bioawk, but my approach "inserts the variable separately", which is probably not optimal: `for seq_id in $(cat id.txt); do bioawk -c fastx -v seq_id="${seq_id}" '$name == seq_id {print ">"$name"\n"$seq}' seq.fasta; done`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$ awk -F'>' 'NR==FNR{ids[$0]; next} NF>1{f=($2 in ids)} f' id.txt seq.fasta
>7P58X:01332:11636
TTCAGCAAGCCGAGTCCTGCGTCGTTACTTCGCTT
CAAGTCCCTGTTCGGGCGCC
>7P58X:01334:11613
ACGAGTGCGTCAGACCCTTTTAGTCAGTGTGGAAAC
```

Comment: How should this be modified to accept a piped seq.fasta file from a previous step?

Comment: `whatever | awk '...' id.txt -`

Answer (score 2):

Following `awk` may help you on same.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next} /^>/{val=$0;sub(/^>/,"",val);flag=val in a?1:0} flag' ids.txt  fasta_file
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing a similar problem. The size of my multi-fasta file is ~ 25G.
I use **sed** instead of **awk**, though my solution is an ugly hack.

First, I extracted the line number of the title of each sequence to a data file.

```
grep -n ">" multi-fasta.fa > multi-fasta.idx
```

What I got is something like this:

```
1:>DM_0000000004
5:>DM_0000000005
11:>DM_0000000007
19:>DM_0000000008
23:>DM_0000000009
```

Then, I extracted the wanted sequence by its title, eg. DM_0000000004, using the scripts below.

```
seqnm=$1
idx0_idx1=`grep -n $seqnm multi-fasta.idx`

idx0=`echo $idx0_idx1 | cut -d ":" -f 1`
idx0plus1=`expr $idx0 + 1`

idx1=`echo $idx0_idx1 | cut -d ":" -f 2`

idx2=`head -n $idx0plus1 multi-fasta.idx | tail -1 | cut -d ":" -f 1`
idx2minus1=`expr $idx2 - 1`

sed ''"$idx1"','"$idx2minus1"'!d' multi-fasta.fa > ${seqnm}.fasta
```

For example, I want to extract the sequence of **DM_0000016115**. The ***idx0_idx1*** variable gives me:

```
7507:42520:>DM_0000016115
```

7507 (***idx0***) is the line number of line **42520:>DM_0000016115** in **multi-fasta.idx**.

42520 (***idx1***) is the line number of line **>DM_0000016115** in **multi-fasta.fa**.

***idx2*** is the line number of the sequence title right beneath the wanted one (**>DM_0000016115**).

At last, using **sed**, we can extract the lines between ***idx1*** and ***idx2 minus 1***, which are the title and the sequence, in which case you can use **grep -A**.

The advantage of this ugly-hack is that it does not require a specific number of lines for each sequence in the multi-fasta file.

What bothers me is this process is slow. For my 25G multi-fasta file, such extraction takes tens of seconds. However, it's much faster than using [**samtools faidx**](https://github.com/merenlab/anvio/issues/1479) .