# How to do multiple match and print different number of lines after each pattern using awk

Tags: bash, awk, grep, bioinformatics, fasta

I have a big file with thousand lines that looks like:

```
>ENST00001234.1
ACGTACGTACGG
TTACCCAGTACG
ATCGCATTCAGC
>ENST00002235.4
TTACGCAT
TAGGCCAG
>ENST00005546.9
TTTATCGC
TTAGGGTAT
```

I want to grep specific ids (after `>` sign), for example, `ENST00001234.1` then want to get lines after the match until the next `>` [regardless of the number of lines]. I want to grep about 63 ids in this way at once.

If I grep `ENST00001234.1` and `ENST00005546.9` ids, the ideal output should be:

```
>ENST00001234.1
ACGTACGTACGG
TTACCCAGTACG
ATCGCATTCAGC
>ENST00005546.9
TTTATCGC
TTAGGGTAT
```

I tried `awk '/ENST00001234.1/ENST00005546.9/{print}'` but it did not help.

Comment: You might be interested in an application called bioawk, developed on top of awk for these purposes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set `>` as the record separator:

```
$ awk -F'\n' -v RS='>' -v ORS= '$1=="ENST00001234.1"{print RS $0}' ip.txt
>ENST00001234.1
ACGTACGTACGG
TTACCCAGTACG
ATCGCATTCAGC
```

- `-F'\n'` to make it easier to compare the search term with first line
- `-v RS='>'` set `>` as input record separator
- `-v ORS=` clear the output record separator, otherwise you'll get extra newline in the output
- `$1=="ENST00001234.1"` this will do string comparison and matches the entire first line, otherwise you'll have to escape regex metacharacters like `.` and add anchors
- `print RS $0` if match is found, print `>` and the record content

---

If you want to match more than one search terms, put them in a file:

```
$ cat f1
ENST00001234.1
ENST00005546.9

$ awk 'BEGIN{FS="\n"; ORS=""}
       NR==FNR{a[$0]; next}
       $1 in a{print RS $0}' f1 RS='>' ip.txt
>ENST00001234.1
ACGTACGTACGG
TTACCCAGTACG
ATCGCATTCAGC
>ENST00005546.9
TTTATCGC
TTAGGGTAT
```

Here, the contents of `f1` is used to build the keys for array `a`. Once the first file is read, `RS='>'` will change the record separator for the second file.

`$1 in a` will check if the first line matches a key in array `a`

Answer (score 3):

***EDIT(Generic solution):*** In case one has to look for multiple strings in Input_file then mention all of them in `awk` variable `search` with `,`(comma) separated and that should print all matched ones(respective lines).

```
awk -v search="ENST00001234.1,ENST00002235.4" '
BEGIN{
  num=split(search,arr,",")
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    look[">"arr[i]]
  }
}
/^>/{
  if($0 in look){ found=1  }
  else          { found="" }
}
found
' Input_file
```

In case you want to read ids(which needs to be searched into Input_file) from another file then try following. Where `look_file` is the file which has all ids needs to be searched and `Input_file` is the actual content file.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  look[">"$0]
}
/^>/{
  if($0 in look){ found=1  }
  else          { found="" }
}
found
' look_file  Input_file
```

---

---

***For single text search:*** Could you please try following. Written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`. One could give string which needs to be searched in variable `search` as per their requirement.

```
awk -v search="ENST00001234.1" '
/^>/{
  if($0==">"search){  found=1  }
  else             {  found="" }
}
found
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk -v search="ENST00001234.1" '     ##Starting awk program from here and setting and setting search variable value what we need to look.
/^>/{                                ##Checking condition if a line starts from > then do following.
  if($0==">"search){  found=1  }     ##Checking condition if current line equals to > search(variable value) then set found to 1 here.
  else             {  found="" }     ##else set found to NULL here.
}
found                                ##Checking condition if found is SET then print that line.
' Input_file                         ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to reinvent the wheel. There are several bioinformatics tools for this task (extract `fasta` sequences using a list of sequence ids). For example, [`seqtk subseq`](https://github.com/lh3/seqtk):

> Extract sequences with names in file name.lst, one sequence name per line:
>
> `seqtk subseq in.fq name.lst > out.fq`

It works with `fasta` files as well.
Use `conda install seqtk` or `conda create --name seqtk seqtk` to install the `seqtk` package, which has other useful functionalities, and is very fast.

**SEE ALSO:**

[Retrieve FASTA sequences using sequence ids](https://gif.biotech.iastate.edu/retrieve-fasta-sequences-using-sequence-ids)
[Extract fasta sequences from a file using a list in another file](https://www.biostars.org/p/319099/)
[How To Extract A Sequence From A Big (6Gb) Multifasta File?](https://www.biostars.org/p/49820/)
[extract sequences from multifasta file by ID in file using awk](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49731386/967621)